# Why does django inside a container needs the "it" flag?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-toolbox

I try to run django on a docker container using sqllite as the db and the django dev server. So far I was able to launch locally the django server:

```
python .\manage.py runserver
```

I can build the docker image using [Dockerfile](https://github.com/RemiBou/Pithocker/blob/master/DockerFile):

```
docker build . -t pythocker
```

But when I run the image with `docker run -p 8000:8000 pythocker` no output is shown and the machine is not reachable, I have to kill the running container.

If I add the `-it` flag on the `docker run` command then the server is running and I can go to `http://192.168.99.100:8000` and display the django welcome page. Why is this flag mandatory here?

Docker logs on the container gives nothing. I also tried to add custom logging inside the manage.py but it's not diplayed in the console or in the docker logs.

I am using the Docker Windows toolbox as I have only a windows home computer.